# Does anyone have a full disassembly guide for an HP P4515x printer?

Tags: hp, printer, manual

We are getting an error at power on that indicates a fan failure.  As this printer is no longer under warranty it is falling on me to open it up and look around.   I have searched HP's website and haven't had any luck.

Any help someone can give me would be awesome!

Answer (score 1):

You want to search for the term "service manual" in conjunction with the model number. It appears that it's a hefty document that is not available in a digital format, or if it is, as you've found, it's well hidden. [Check out eBay for a copy](http://cgi.ebay.com/HP-LaserJet-P4014-4015-4515-series-Service-Manual-PDF-/150412004303).

Answer (score 1):

Since the fan is not listed in any of the parts for this printer, this is something that's **highly** unlikely to be in a readily available PDF for download. You may be better off downloading the User Guide ([link](http://bizsupport2.austin.hp.com/bc/docs/support/SupportManual/c01295101/c01295101.pdf), will stale out after a while) to get a better feel for internal layout before you dismantle it yourself. Take notes.